# C++/CLI: CA2123: Requires SecurityCriticalAttribute?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, code-analysis

I am a little lost on erros like that:

> Warning   7   CA2123 : Microsoft.Security
>   : Add the following security attribute
>   to
>   'RithmicConnector::Connect(String^)'
>   in order to match a LinkDemand on base
>   method 'IConnector::Connect(String^)':
>   'SecurityCriticalAttribute'.  c:\work\nettecture\tradex\source\tradex.connectivity.rithmic\rithmicconnector.cpp   52  Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic

Where do I add the SecurityCriticalAttribute?

I tried on the header file - but the error does not disappear. I have one of those pretty much on every exposed method of a (managed C++) interface DLL.

And I want CA to run through.

How do I fix those?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to do two things:

1. Add [assembly: SecurityCritical] to the assembly.
2. Add [SecurityCritical] attribute to the specific methods containing critical code(or whatever else you wish to decorate).

Here's a blog entry that might be helpful [Using Transparency in CLR](http://www.codingodyssey.com/2009/05/18/using-transparency-in-clr-2/)